# Multiply vector elements correspondingly in C++

Tags: c++

So I have two vectors:

```
vector<int> v1(size);
vector<int> v2(size);
```

and what I want is to calculate `A[0]*B[0] - A[1]*B[1] - A[2]*B[2] - ... - A[n-1]*B[n-1]`. I've tried the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t size = 4;
    vector<int> product; int i;

    vector<int> v1(size);
    vector<int> v2(size);

    v1[0] = 2;   v2[0] = 4;
    v1[1] = 5;   v2[1] = 1;
    v1[2] = 9;   v2[2] = 6;
    v1[3] = 3;   v2[3] = 7;

    for(i=1;i < v1.size();++i){
        product.push_back(v1[i]*v2[i]);
    }

    for(vector<int>::const_iterator i = product.begin(); i != product.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

However, this would return `5 54 21` as of `v1[1]*v2[1], v1[2]*v2[2] and v1[3]*v2[3]` and I want to subtract them from each other: `5-54-21`.

Comment: print `-` instead of space?

Comment: @saadtaame, that would produce a string `5-54-21-`.

Comment: These days you can save yourself some typing with `vector<int> v1{2,5,9,3};`, `vector<int> v2{4,1,6,7};` and `for(auto p : product) cout << p << ' ';`

Comment: I tried it before but I ended up with this: `in C++98 'v1' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'|` Still on 98, yeah..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in your formula, the first product must be added (IOW is positive), while the remaining are subtracted. So you must treat the two cases differently.

Secondly, you can perform the calculation easily by computing an ongoing result, starting from zero:

```
int result = 0;
if (size >= 1) {
    result += v1[0]*v2[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
        result -= v1[i]*v2[i];
}
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: I totally missed that. Will accept ASAP, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
vector<int> v1{2,5,9,3};
vector<int> v2{4,1,6,7};

int result = std::inner_product(++v1.beginn(),v1.end(),++v2.begin(),v1[0]*v2[0],std::minus<>,std::multiplies<>);
```

(with C++14)

```
int result = std::inner_product(++v1.beginn(),v1.end(),++v2.begin(),v1[0]*v2[0],std::minus<int>,std::multiplies<int>);
```

(with C++98)